# Ambiguous title in thesis report

Tags: ambiguity, titles

Is the thesis title below ambiguous, and if so, how should it be expressed instead?

> Predicting split atoms in mountain chains with virtual beetles

I want to say that I predict shared atoms, and the method is to use virtual beetles. The atoms that I estimate and predict the split for are found in mountain chains. But, what I wonder is whether the sentence can be interpreted to mean that I'm talking about mountain chains where virtual beetles exist?

So, how should I express the sentence so it can be understood that my method is virtual beetles, and not small robotic insects?

Comment: Are you using random nouns to as a general question, or is this a real title? I have no clue what this is about, just curious.

Comment: Can you use "Using virtual beetles to predict split atoms in mountain chains"?

Comment: @Flater yes I am, it was very clever of you to notice that ;) However, should I not have done that? Maybe it is hard to give me feedback when it's a "nonsense" title. The purpose was to not "exploit" my real thesis title as I don't want anyone to think that I have "plagiarized" even one sentence of my report.

Comment: @YosefBaskin actually that is a good idea. I thought of something starting with "Using" (but I didn't write it in the question because I did not want to "bias" my replies..).. But I did not think of the exact way you expressed it, I think it can work because it is much shorter than what I have tried so far. Thanks alot

Comment: @StephenJohnson: I'm a developer, so I often resort to placeholder names like `Foo` and `Bar` (developer favorites). However, logic works independent of context (that's the goal at least). This does not hold true for language. Even if a response is technically correct, it might still sound stilted because there is a better way of saying it for your specific context.

Comment: @Flater you are right, I know what you mean, but that is a good Point. Actually, the advice from Yosef worked quite well after translating it into the topic I am writing about :) PS. I am a developer too so I usually use foobar aswell, but I figured normal people will not relate.

Comment: Yes, it's ambiguous. The intended meaning is dominant, but the sentence could also be argued to say that the act of predicting caused atoms to split. It's somewhat plausible if you're writing about quantum mechanics. Your alternate interpretation of the latter part of the sentence works with both interpretations of the first part. Since this is a title, there is some latitude for ambiguity; the rest of the work should make clear which version was meant.

Comment: Predicting split atoms in mountain chains *using* virtual beetles.

Answer (score 1):

Your title is ambiguous in that it fails to identify which phrase (either splitting atoms or mountain chains) the virtual beetles are associated with.

It could mean either:

> (Predicting split atoms in mountain chains) with virtual beetles

or:

> Predicting split atoms in (mountain chains with virtual beetles)

The first version is your intended meaning.

It should be made clear that the virtual beetle method was used to split the atoms. With your current sentence order this will prove difficult.

As thesis titles are intended to be helpful, I would write:

> Virtual beetle method predicts split atoms in mountain chains

but there are several alternatives.

Comment: I don't think you should encourage the practice of using a conclusion as thesis title. 1. It does not describe the subject of the investigation 2. It precludes the possibility of the reader making his own judgment about the conclusions. It is really bad psychology — as a thesis examiner I would be immediately prejudiced against the student. For goodness sake do him a favour and stick with your appropriate suggestions.

Comment: @David; it's not a real thesis, so, using the concepts given, it should be impossible to make a meaningful title.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to make an answer. You are right, the title in the question is not real as the nouns have been replaced by random, yet kind of related, words. However, I realized when I read my title today, that even if you interpret it as intended, i.e., the first of your quotes, I think it is still ambiguous. Why? Because someone might think I have virtual beetle friends that helps me with the predicting.